# What does "firefox --recording-output <file>" do?

Tags: firefox

Firefox 46.0 has two "flags" called `--recording` and `--recording-output`. I've searched the net and nothing was said about them. Also I tried it myself - didn't notice a change.

Comment: Top of my Google search for `firefox "recording-output"` was [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Platform/GFX/Moz2D#Recording_and_playback) which seems to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those flags introduce a new feature in Firefox which allows users to record web pages drawing for debugging purposes using Microsoft Azure. The drawing could include bitmaps drawn, and all font true-type data etc. These information in form of traces, could help in measuring performance and fixing bugs across Azure back-ends.

See [Presenting the Azure Drawing Recorder](http://www.basschouten.com/blog1.php/presenting-the-azure-drawing-recorder), [Add ability to record azure page drawing](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=854468)
and [Application Architecture on Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/architecture-overview/)
for more info.
Note that this is currently only available in Microsoft platforms.